# Wordpress: Dynamic query for taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, search, taxonomy

I have a **search form** consists of several "select" which list various **terms** of a **taxonomy** ('State'). By pressing the submit button, I pass the information to a search results page on which I build the query.

The problem is that I need to build the ***query dynamically*** because it is not obligatory to choose values ​​for each of the "select". So some values ​​are sent empty.

For example:

```
$country = $_POST["country"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
```

If $city is empty, the query should be like:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'state' => $country
    )
);
```

But if $country and $city are not empty, de query should be like:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'state' => $country,
    'state' => $city
    )
);
```

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : null;
$country = isset($_POST['country']) ? (isset($_POST['city']) ? ' ('. $_POST['country'] .')' : $_POST['country']) : null;

$state = $city . $country;
```

This code will show:

- City and Country filled: Caracas (Venezuela)
- Only City: Caracas
- Only Country: Venezuela

And your query:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'state' => $state,
    )
);
```